# Detecting duplicate webpages among large number of URLs

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, web, architecture, search-engine

From a quote in [google blogspot](http://googleblog.blogspot.in/2008/07/we-knew-web-was-big.html),

```
"In fact, we found even more than 1 trillion individual links, but not all of 
them lead to unique web pages. Many pages have multiple URLs with exactly the same
content or URLs that are auto-generated copies of each other. Even after removing
those exact duplicates . . . "
```

How does Google detect those exact duplicate webpages or documents?  Any idea on Algorithm that Google uses?

Comment: Store a hash-value for each page. If hash is equal, compare the content.

Comment: How do u compute a hash-value for each page. based on page size, content of the page?

Comment: As you need to read the page for indexing, you can easily also compute a hash based on the content. Size would lead to too many false positive detections.

Comment: what other approaches for hashvalue computations? like the above two?

Comment: Siplest, and maybe fasted way, would be e.g a 64bit value which is `xor` of all 8-byte blocks. (of cause other sizes than 64bit are also possible)

Answer (score 1):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinHash:

> A large scale evaluation has been conducted by Google in 2006 [10] to
>   compare the performance of Minhash and Simhash[11] algorithms. In 2007
>   Google reported using Simhash for duplicate detection for web
>   crawling[12] and using Minhash and LSH for Google News
>   personalization.[13]

A search for Simhash turns up this page:

<s>https://liangsun.org/posts/a-python-implementation-of-simhash-algorithm/</s>

https://github.com/leonsim/simhash

which references a paper written by google employees: [Detecting near-duplicates for web crawling](http://www.wwwconference.org/www2007/papers/paper215.pdf)

**Abstract:**

> Near-duplicate web documents are abundant. Two such documents differ
>   from each other in a very small portion that displays advertisements,
>   for example. Such differences are irrelevant for web search. So the
>   quality of a web crawler increases if it can assess whether a newly
>   crawled web page is a near-duplicate of a previously crawled web page
>   or not. In the course of developing a near-duplicate detection system
>   for a multi-billion page repository, we make two research
>   contributions. First, we demonstrate that Charikar's fingerprinting
>   technique is appropriate for this goal. Second, we present an
>   algorithmic technique for identifying existing f-bit fingerprints that
>   differ from a given fingerprint in at most k bit-positions, for small
>   k. Our technique is useful for both online queries (single
>   fingerprints) and all batch queries (multiple fingerprints).
>   Experimental evaluation over real data confirms the practicality of
>   our design.

Another Simhash paper:

http://simhash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/paper/SimHashWithBib.pdf‎

Answer (score 0):

possible solutions

exact methods

1) brute force: compare every new page to all visited pages (very slow and inefficient)

2) calculate hash of every visited page (md5,sha1) and store the hashes in a database and look up every new page's hash in the database

3)standard Boolean model of information retrieval (BIR)

........many other possible methods

near exact methods

1)fuzzy hash

2)latent semantic indexing

....

Comment: I would not use md5 or sha1, because they are quite heavy to compute and we do not need the cryptographic features of these. A much simplear and faster to compute hash could do the job as well.

Comment: In particular, Google could construct a hash based on the search terms they are already indexing.